# Unitize the columns of matrix

Tags: matlab

Given a matrix **d x n** (d-dimensional, n-object) I would like to compute the unit length vector of each columns. (i.e the resultant matrix should have unit length in every column)

how can i do it without looping every column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the L2 norm. In that case,

```
normalizedVector = bsxfun(@rdivide,vector,sqrt(sum(vector.^2,1)));
```

will have unit length along each column.